# How to set DNS to my IP and port - Atlantic.Net

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, internal-dns, dns-hosting, dns-zone

[image]I'm new to host my `ruby on rails` application on the server. I have bought a server from **Atlantic.Net** and running my project on a `port` let's say `port-3001`. Now I'm unable to set my domain to my `IP` and a specified `port`. Please suggest anyone what and how to do... ?